# Probability of generating set

Tags: probability

Imagine we have a box with $5$ unique letters. 
We want to create a unordered set of $3$ letters

1. Probability of getting first letter of $5$ letters is $1/5$
2. Probability of getting second letter is $1/4$
3. Probability of getting third letter is $1/3$

So probability of getting any set is $\frac{1}{5*4*3} = 1/60$

Now imagine the same box with $5$ unique letters. And we still want to create a unordered set of $3$ letters. But using different approach:

Pulling out first letter:

- Take any of letters with probability $1/5$
- Write down value of letter on paper
- Put letter back to box

Pulling out second letter:

- Take any of letters with probability $1/5$
- If letter is the same as first one, put it back and try until we get a different letter
- The probability of getting any letter is $1/5$
- The probability of getting new letter is $4/5$
- After getting new letter write down it value on the paper
- Put letter back to box

Pulling out third letter:

- Take any of letters with probability $1/5$.
- if letter is the same as first or second one, put it back and try until we get different letter
- The probability of getting any letter is $1/5$
- The probability of getting new letter is $3/5$
- After getting new letter write down it value on the paper
- Put letter back to box

Questions:

- How to caclulate probability of getting any set with second approach?
- Will probability be the same (in second approach) of getting any set?

Comment: If a set is unordered and the $5$ letters are different then without replacement there are $10$ equally likely subsets of $3$ each with probability $\frac{1}{10}$ of being drawn

Comment: Your second method (a form of rejection sampling with replacement) has exactly the same probabilities of a particular final outcome as your first without replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability for drawing $1,2,$ then $3$ is $\tfrac 15\tfrac 14\tfrac 13$.

The probability for drawing $1,3,$ then $2$ is $\tfrac 15\tfrac 14\tfrac 13$.

The probability for drawing $2,1,$ then $3$ is $\tfrac 15\tfrac 14\tfrac 13$.

... and such.   Indeed, there are six ways to order $\{1,2,3\}$ so the oprobability for drawing *any order* of a particular set of three distinct numbers from the source is $6\cdot\tfrac 15\tfrac 14\tfrac 13$.   That is $\tfrac 1{10}$.

Or we might evaluate the probability for selecting 3 particular numbers when selecting any 3 from 6, without bias or replacement. $$\dfrac {\binom 33}{\binom 53}=\dfrac{1}{10}$$

---

The second verse is the same as the first.   When you select with replacement repeatedly *until* you obtain a new element, you are effectively selecting without replacement.